# Implement watcher to send mail if no input in past n seconds

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

i am trying to set the watcher for the following scenario

if there is no document inserted into index for past n hours, send out an alert. So that we can check if there is any issue in connectivity breakdown between our nodes and elastic search.

To implement such scenario, i used the following json for replication.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://10.x.x.1:9200/_watcher/watch/log_error_watch' -d '{
  "trigger" : { "schedule" : { "interval" : "10s" } },
  "input" : {
    "search" : {
      "request" : {
        "indices" : [ "test" ],
        "body" : {
          "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "array_compare": {
      "ctx.payload.aggregations.test.buckets" : { 
        "path": "doc_count" ,
        "lt": { 
          "value": 1, 
          "quantifier": "some" 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "actions" : {
    "log_error" : {
      "logging" : {
        "text" : "No data for past 10 seconds"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But its not putting alert message in logs. Can someone please help me with the logic inside condition section.

Comment: Your search input query doesn't have any aggregations. Why are you using this condition that check aggregations? `ctx.payload.aggregations.test.buckets`

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition instead:

```
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gt": 0
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: if number of hits greater than 0 this will send alert. i.e. if there is any document inserted within 10seconds i will get alert. .However, i am looking for the opposite case. if no documents in 10seconds send an alert.

Comment: "ctx.payload.hits.total" will calculate total number of hits within 10 seconds. or it will calculate total records in the index right from the beginning

Comment: It is not calculating anything. You run a query in your input, and in your case I see it's `match_all`. The result of that query will be passed to the condition. So you run `match_all` and the condition checks if there are any results returned. That's it.

Comment: i tried setting this watcher. the alarm is getting triggered only whenever there is a message . I am looking for the scenario , when there are no messages it should post an alarm

Comment: What do you mean "whenever there is a message"?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "trigger": {
      "schedule": {
        "interval": "5m"
      }
    },
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
          "indices": [
            "filebeat-*"
          ],
          "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
          "body": {
            "size": 0, 
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "filter": [
         {
           "terms": {
             "product": [
               "ABC",
               "XYZ"
             ]
           }
         },
         {
           "term": {
             "env": "PROD"
           }
         },
         { "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-1m",
        "lte": "now",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
             }
         }}
       ]
     }
   },
   "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "hostname",
            "size": 100,
            "min_doc_count": 0,
            "include": ".*PROD.*"
      }
     }
   }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "array_compare": {
        "ctx.payload.aggregations.NAME.buckets": {
          "path": "doc_count",
          "eq": {
              "value": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "actions": {
      "send_email": {
        "email": {
          "profile": "standard",
          "to": [
            "email@email.com"
          ],
          "subject": "No Logs in Kibana for 5 minutes",
          "body": {
            "html": """<h2><font color="red">Team, <br>Logs are not coming for below environment for 5 Minutes</br></font></h2>
  <table>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Environment</th>
      <th>Doc Count</th>
    </tr>
  {{#ctx.payload.aggregations.NAME.buckets}}
  <tr>
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{doc_count}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/ctx.payload.aggregations.NAME.buckets}}
  </table>"""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.